# VRTK valid object policy

Tags: unity-game-engine, vrtk

How do I limit the VRTK snap drop zone so that I can only drop one specific object in the zone? I tried to add the vrtk valid policy list where specified the element according to the name of the object but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the name is correct as they are case sensitive. Try using another check type such a Script/Layer.

https://vrtoolkit.readme.io/docs/vrtk_policylist